# Compare dates with four digit years

Tags: python, date

I need to compare dates in this format:

```
'03/31/2018' # month/day/year
```

I tried to use the datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime("03/31/2018", "%m/%d/%y")
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 18
```

If I use a two digit year:

```
dt.strptime("03/31/18", "%m/%d/%y")
```

It works, but in this case I need to compare using the whole four digits year

Comment: Use `%Y` for 4-digit years instead of `%y`. Case matters.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a big Y

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt.strptime("03/31/2018", "%m/%d/%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0)
```